# How to drag a custompainter widget in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-custompainter

I created the clock in the image using custompainter. My objective is to drag the clock hands(second ,hour and minute hands) to set the time. How can i drag these hands around the clock from a fixed center point in flutter?

[image]

Comment: check how they did it in [time_picker.dart](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/135454af32477f815a7525073027a3ff9eff1bfd/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/time_picker.dart#L1056)

Comment: @pskink i have checked your code. I do have a question though. if we want to rotate a custom painter do we need to use matrix?

Comment: no, you can always use `Canvas.rotate` but believe me matrix is better

Comment: @pskink will look it up